# Enterprise Modules not working with React 18 and AG Grid 31.0.3

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a grid built with `ag-grid` and trying to leverage enterprise features like server-side database, side panel, and context menu.

None of these work on my machine, if I simply try to use the documentation's code. Here I am trying to enable SideBar and ContextMenu.

```
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-quartz.css';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import { AgGridReact } from 'ag-grid-react';
import { AgGridReact as AgGridReactType } from 'ag-grid-react/lib/agGridReact';
import { SelectionChangedEvent, ColDef } from 'ag-grid-community';
...

return (
          <AgGridReact
            ref={gridRef}
            rowData={rowData}
            columnDefs={colDefs}
            gridOptions={gridOptions}
            onSelectionChanged={onRowSelect}
            allowContextMenuWithControlKey={true}
            sideBar={true}

          />);
```

And then on console I see issues like this

```
ag-grid-community.auto.esm.js:799 AG Grid: unable to use sideBar as the SideBarModule is not registered. Check if you have registered the module:
           
    import { ModuleRegistry } from '@ag-grid-community/core';
    import { SideBarModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/side-bar';
    
    ModuleRegistry.registerModules([ SideBarModule ]);

For more info see: https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid/modules/
```

Even when I try to use this code, the features don't work. I can also try to import modules as a prop

```
          <AgGridReact
            ref={gridRef}
            rowData={rowData}
            columnDefs={colDefs}
            gridOptions={gridOptions}
            onSelectionChanged={onRowSelect}
            allowContextMenuWithControlKey={true}
            sideBar={true}
            modules={[SidebarModule]}
          />);
```

However, when I run this project on someone else's machine, none of these warnings appear and without additional imports, the features work.
I can't replicate how to do this on my machine. We've both tried reinstalling the dependencies and have same setup and continue to see different results.

I have 3 packages in my React 18 repo: `ag-grid-community`, `ag-grid-enterprise`, `ag-grid-react`, all at version `31.0.3`.